# Query multiple post types, but different order for each

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, query, meta-query

I have a query which searches 2 post types as below:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => ['post', 'promotion'],
    'posts_per_page'         => 12,
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    's'                      => isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '',
);
```

This orders them by default, by published date.

I need to add a third post type `events`. This however needs to be sorted by a custom field `event_date` `asc` and to disregard those which the `event_date` is in the past. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be done? While keeping the pagination and search.

Thanks in advance

F

Comment: I would strongly recommend a second, separate query for your event posts, and then merge them using PHP before output (or however you wish to display them) - use a [meta query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) for querying for your `event_date` custom field.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay. I did think about this, but how would the pagination work. I would like to show 10 per page. It might be on page 1 there is 8 posts and 2 promotions, and then on page 2 (the next 10) there is 5 posts and 5 promotions. Thanks